# Numerical methods/analysis forums

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I recently started a course on Numerical analysis and would like to know what are the active online communities/forums and sites to learn and follow, in the area. Please share a list below if possible as it may be useful to many others like me. Thanks.

Comment: A good place to start might be https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This site is not bad at all, be sure.